# How can I play a sound when a user presses a button in a MessageBox?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to ask a user for either yes or no, and I would like it to play a sound when the user selects no. But my code plays a sound if the user selects yes or no.

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Buscar Informações do CEP Online?", "CEP Não Encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //do something
   // Process.Start("http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/servicos/dnec/index.do");
    Process.Start(
        "http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/servicos/dnec/consultaLogradouroAction.do?Metodo=listaLogradouro&CEP=" +
        maskedTextBoxCep.Text + "&TipoConsulta=cep");
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    //do something else
    SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the sound is not being played because of something else (ie. some configuration setting in Windows?)

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, what line of code is producing the sound?  How is that line of code being reached?  It's one thing to guess, but you can validate this with your debugger.

Comment: When I step through in a debugger the sound plays when Process.Start(); is executed

Comment: I don't know how critical your service is, but maybe you should remove/replace the url from the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some computers I have a code with Process.Start that will make a exclamation noise before running the process, I'm using the same program in 5 different machines and only 1 will beep, the machine that beeps has the same OS as 2 other machines, I still don't know why, try to change your sound to a different one to see if the sound you are hearing is not from the Process.Start "Bug"